# Updating a shared contact is getting error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have an issue when I try to update (PATCH) a shared contact with Microsoft-Graph.

I'm getting this message:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorInternalServerError",
        "message": "An internal server error occurred. The operation failed., This session itself is a delegated session.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "d12ca994-a3f6-4f3a-956e-ed4dc43bf72b",
            "date": "2018-08-23T22:21:05"
        }
    }
}
```

What's going on?

Update: I attach an image from Graph Explorer
[Evidence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcnlg.png)

Comment: Have you tried this in Graph Explorer signed in as your tenant user? https://aka.ms/ge 
I'm assuming you've seen the syntax to call this on the docs? https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/contact_update

What are you trying to update?

Comment: I don't have much of an answer for you, but that request-id does not show up in the Graph logs.  The error message seems to be related to an Authentication issue.  Can you describe where this code is running and how you are authorizing the call?

Comment: @JeremyThakeMSFT yes I do,  this is the scenario, we a have two user me and aa coworker he shared his outlook contacts folder with me, I can fetch contacts in his folder but when I try to update the givenName property, the response that I get is that.

Comment: @DarrelMiller i'm running it on SPfx webpart, but the authentication process was with Adal.js library. we add an AAD secure application in Azure and grant permissions for Contact.ReadWrite, and Contact.ReadWrite.Shared In fact we can updated our own contacts but we can't update others contacts.

Comment: Thanks for your response :D

Comment: @luisArraiz so you are trying to update a contact in someone elses contacts? The API will honour whatever you can do in the user experience in Outlook. I do not believe you can edit other peoples contacts. Obviously a better error message than this should occur for sure. I'm going to double check with the PM.

Answer (score 1):

After talking with the engineering team, this scenario is not supported right now. We are going to update the documentation to explain this for future reference.

Comment: Thanks for your respone and support